# multiple legends in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The problem: I have plots with 8 lines, and need to put the legend for all 8 lines into the plot. The document format is IEEE, and the plots need to fit in the single column.

The current solution: I've been able to split the plots by creating two axis, like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=Average Degree, ylabel=Total Weight, legend style={at={(.95,.69)}, label={[font=\footnotesize]left:K/Y+R}, font=\footnotesize, anchor=south east}, legend columns=2, cycle list name={four-1-0}]
    \addplot+[grt] table  [x=links, y=star-red]{\averageone};
    \addplot+[grt] table  [x=links, y=star-red]{\averagetwo};
    \addplot+[grt] table  [x=links, y=star-red]{\averagethree};
    \addplot+[grt] table  [x=links, y=star-red]{\averagefour};
    \addplot+[inv] table [x=links, y=mat-red]{\averageone};
    \addplot+[inv] table [x=links, y=mat-red]{\averagetwo};
    \addplot+[inv] table [x=links, y=mat-red]{\averagethree};
    \addplot+[inv] table [x=links, y=mat-red]{\averagefour};
    \legend{(120),(120),(480),(960)}
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line=none,axis y line=none, legend style={at={(.95,.68)}, label={[font=\footnotesize]left:DGMM+R}, font=\footnotesize, anchor=north east}, legend columns=2, cycle list name={four-0-1}]
    \addplot+[inv] table  [x=links, y=star-red]{\averageone};
    \addplot+[inv] table  [x=links, y=star-red]{\averagetwo};
    \addplot+[inv] table  [x=links, y=star-red]{\averagethree};
    \addplot+[inv] table  [x=links, y=star-red]{\averagefour};
    \addplot+[bls] table [x=links, y=mat-red]{\averageone};
    \addplot+[bls] table [x=links, y=mat-red]{\averagetwo};
    \addplot+[bls] table [x=links, y=mat-red]{\averagethree};
    \addplot+[bls] table [x=links, y=mat-red]{\averagefour};
    \legend{,,,,(120),(120),(480),(960)}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The first axis is visible, the second is invisible. The `[inv]` style creates a line with no line, the `[grn]` and `[bls]` tags generate the orange and blue lines, and the cycle lists `four-0-1` and `four-1-0` set the marks on the invisible lines to `none`. There are orange lines with circles of the same color as the squares on the blue lines in the bottom two lines, but they are hard to see in this picture. The macros are defined as follows:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotstableread{plts/experiment8b1_av.tab}\averageone
\pgfplotstableread{plts/experiment8b2_av.tab}\averagetwo
\pgfplotstableread{plts/experiment8b3_av.tab}\averagethree
\pgfplotstableread{plts/experiment8b4_av.tab}\averagefour
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{four-1-0}{%
  every mark/.append style={fill=teal}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=green}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=orange}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=pink}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=none}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=none}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=none}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=none}\\%
}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{four-0-1}{%
  every mark/.append style={fill=none}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=none}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=none}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=none}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=teal}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=green}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=orange}\\%
  every mark/.append style={fill=pink}\\%
}
\tikzstyle{bls}=[blue, solid, mark=square*]
\tikzstyle{grt}=[red, solid, mark=*]
\tikzstyle{inv}=[draw=none]
```

Obviously, this won't compile unless you have the relevant [data](http://code.google.com/p/graphcomplexity/downloads/detail?name=experiment8bav.zip&can=2&q=) files, but the output looks like this:

[image: graph]

The question: Is there an elegant way to accomplish something very similar to this without building two axis? In some of the other plots I have the two legends have to be in completely different parts of the plot in order to fit them in.

Comment: I'm confused by the part about "the plots need to fit in the single column".  What is the obvious choice that isn't acceptable in this case?

Comment: As opposed to just making the plot big enough to span two columns. IEEEtrans is a two column page.

Comment: You really should include your "tons of preamble".

Comment: I don't see why. The only lines that aren't are `\usepackage` statements are style definitions, cyclelist definitions, and data references. None of which have anything to do with the problem, and at least some of which wouldn't do you any good without the data.

Comment: @Philosodad. The convention, both here and in other places you can get TeX-related help, is that a minimal example should be something that others can copy-and-paste into their editor of choice. The idea is to minimise both work and misunderstanding by those trying to answer the question. It's always interesting to see what some people feel is 'obvious', for example completely non-standard document classes.

Comment: I understand the convention. The difficulty, in this particular case, is that without the actual data files the preamble doesn't help at all. I will add the style definitions, but it still won't be compilable.

Comment: Added a link to the data files.

Answer (score 19):

I'll give it a shot: This solution does not create proper "legends", but merely boxed nodes, so you lose all the nice setup options. It could also probably be solved with a lot more automation (counters, looping and the like).

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot[label=l1]{0.1*x};
\label{p1}
\addplot{0.2*x};
\label{p2}
\addplot{0.3*x};
\label{p3}
\addplot{0.4*x};
\label{p4}
\addplot{0.5*x};
\label{p5}
\addplot{0.6*x};
\label{p6}

\end{axis}

% Draw first "Legend" node using a left justified shortstack, position using relative axis coordinates
\node [draw,fill=white] at (rel axis cs: 0.8,0.3) {\shortstack[l]{
\ref{p1} $0.1 \cdot x$ \\
\ref{p2} $0.2 \cdot x$ \\
\ref{p3} $0.3 \cdot x$}};

% Second "Legend" node
\node [draw,fill=white] at (rel axis cs: 0.3,0.8) {\shortstack[l]{
\ref{p4} $0.4 \cdot x$ \\
\ref{p5} $0.5 \cdot x$ \\
\ref{p6} $0.6 \cdot x$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Six plots with two independent pseudo-legends]

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Very strangely, this strategy does not work with pgfplots externalization. It looks like the label/ref system loses the legend information.

Comment: I find the same thing as @pluton, except occasionally when something else in the picture is broken, which is weird.  I've tried compiling numerous times to let the labels resolve, but nothing helps.  I'd really like a solution for this.

Comment: Just came across this rather old post, but I will comment anyways:
To get the references right, you need to specify `aux in dpth=true` when configuring `tikzexternalize`

Comment: It's working fine for me