# pgfplots, custom legend and tikz library external

Tags: pgfplots, cross-referencing, tikz-external, legend

I try to create Tikz figure with several `pgfplots` subplots. I want to have one legend for them since they all have the same curves. I found out from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20926/tikz-legend-in-caption) that i can label and than reference each curve. I used that to create simple legend at the bottom of the subplots. And it looked just fine when I tried it as a separate file. Then I put it in my thesis where I use the Tikz `external` library which solves the TeX memory problem I encountered before because I have many plots. The problem that occurs can be reproduced by this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) };\label{plot:p1}
\end{axis}
\node (A) at (1,-1) {\ref{plot:p1} Plot 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

(I'm using just one plot here instead of subplots for simplicity).
Notice the question marks for the missing reference in the first image. Of course, if I comment out the 4th line (don't use externalize) the reference turns out just fine (the second image). So I wonder:

> How can I get the reference and still use externalize?

P.S.: TexLive 2011 on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Section *7.1.1 Using the Automatic Externalization Framework of TikZ* from pgfplots manual explains why you have this problem and how to solve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pgfplots: externalization and legend referencing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37471/pgfplots-externalization-and-legend-referencing)

Answer (score 4):

As Ignasi said in the comment, this doesn't work completely automatically.

From the [pgfplots manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots):

> There is just a special case if a `\label`/`\ref` drawn as a
>   `tikzpicture`. This is, for example, the case for the legend `\ref`
>   images or for the `\pgfplotslegendfromname` feature. In such cases,
>   you need to proceed as for case a) since `mode=convert with system
>   call` can't handle that stuff on its own.

Case a) suggests to

> consider using `mode=list and make` or copy{paste the system call for
>   the image(s) and issue it manually.

Your example works for me if I add

```
\pgfkeys{
    /tikz/external/mode=list and make
}
```

to the file and run `make -B -f <filename>.makefile` after the first compile run.

Comment: Important: you may need to deliver the `.dpth` files along with the `.pdf` for every figure. See also [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240876/can-we-get-references-into-externalized-pgfplots-images-to-work). (I don't actually know if it applies to this case, but it may.)