# pgfplots - subplots with common legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend

This is a followup question of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36786/4566). It uses the same MWE but about a different issue so a separate it here. I used Tikz node to create the custom legend but used absolute positioning to place it where I wanted it to appear (below the plots, in the middle). I always try to use relative positioning when I create my Tikz images, but I don't know how to do it here. Or maybe there is some totally different approach in producing subplots with common legend?

Comment: There's an example in the PGFplots manual called "Legends Outside Of an Axis" which might do what you want. If it doesn't, could you include an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I had a similar issue; finally I did a workaround by adding empty plots with the same style to one of the axis, then putting the legend outside the axis.

Comment: Without a full MWE, I think this is 'too localized'. Edit in a MWE then flag and it will be reopened.