# pgfplots: externalization and legend referencing

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external, legend

There are some issues when using the pgfplots option `legend to name` together with externalization. When I disable externalization, everything works fine. When I enable externalization, I get an error

```
! Undefined control sequence. 

l.1 ...every legend to name picture/.try]\pgfplots@legend@to@name
```

and my document wont compile. Without the `legend to name` option, externalization works fine on the other hand. I am using version 1.5 of pgfplots according to `\pgfplotsversion`. A short example follows.

```
\documentclass{report}

% begin of externalization
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\tikzexternalize
% end of externalization

\begin{document}

% example from manual, page 166
\pgfplotsset{footnotesize,samples=10}
\begin{center}% note that \centering uses less vspace...
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend columns=-1,
legend entries={$(x+0)^k$;,$(x+1)^k$;,$(x+2)^k$;,$(x+3)^k$},
legend to name=named, % critical line
title={$k=1$}]
\addplot {x};
\addplot {x+1};
\addplot {x+2};
\addplot {x+3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={$k=2$}]
\addplot {x^2};
\addplot {(x+1)^2};
\addplot {(x+2)^2};
\addplot {(x+3)^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={$k=3$}]
\addplot {x^3};
\addplot {(x+1)^3};
\addplot {(x+2)^3};
\addplot {(x+3)^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\ref{named}
\end{center}
% end of example

\end{document}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I found a solution [here](http://pgfplots-features.706524.n3.nabble.com/Pgfplots-features-groupplot-legend-outside-of-an-axis-and-externalizing-everything-td1676716.html). Just use `\tikzexternaldisable\ref{named}\tikzexternalenable` instead of `\ref{named}`.

Comment: Put it in as an answer. I didn't know this so I reckon it'll be a good addition.

Comment: Externalization can not handle referenced legends, so one has to turn it off for such cases.

**First possibility:**

Instead of `\cref{legendlabel}`, always write `\tikzexternaldisable\ref{legendlabel}\tikzexternalenable`.

Comment: **Second possibility:**

Use a preamble `\pgfplotsset{invoke before crossref tikzpicture={\tikzexternaldisable},invoke after crossref tikzpicture={\tikzexternalenable}}` and then reference legends normally with `\cref{legendlabel}`. It might be possible that this second possibility also prevents other pictures from being externalized, I have not tested this out.

Source of this answer: [Forum][1].


  [1]: http://pgfplots-features.706524.n3.nabble.com/Pgfplots-features-groupplot-legend-outside-of-an-axis-and-externalizing-everything-td1676716.html

Comment: I am not allowed to answer my own question so fast. Wtf, are you kidding me? Nevertheless, please edit my last two comments into an answer. Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong putting your answer to your own question. Also, you don't need to accept it right away. This SE site is pretty open about such things when compared to other SE sites.

Comment: You do not understand: the software of this board does not let me answer my own question until 8 hours have passed. This is ridiculous.

Comment: @Hendrik Wow, I did not know that.

Comment: See also the related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36786/pgfplots-custom-legend-and-tikz-library-external

Comment: @Hendrik please post your comments (especially the second) as an answer. This was most useful. Unfortunately it does not work with `\cref` for me, just `\ref`, weird

Comment: @Hendrik the second version is not working, but the first does and is much better than disabling externalization for the whole image which was my idea first.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is caused by shortcomings of the default conversion mode.

As explained in some of the comments, disabling the automatic conversion is one approach to solve the problem (compare the good comments of Hendrik).

However, image externalization of the small legend pictures *is* possible, although not by means of the default conversion mode.

Here is another solution which allows to externalize the small picture as well:

Call the externalization for the `\ref` picture command either manually (in this case, `force remake` needs to be disabled) or using the `mode=list and make` .

From my point of view, this approach is preferrable over the locally disabled externalization -- but *only* if you are willing to use use `mode=list and make` and `make -f <texfile>.makefile` to convert your images.

If you are using windows or if invoking `make -f <texfile>.makefile` is undesired, you should stick with the answer of Hendrik.

---

For the records and for the technically interested audience, I will summarize what's going on here:

1. as explained in the log file of the "crossref picture", the automatic externalization of the small `\ref` pictures does not work with the default conversion mode:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, image externalization failed: the resulting image was EMPTY. I tried to externalize 'P-figure_crossref0', but it seems there is no such image in the document!?  
   You are currently using 'mode=convert with system call'. This problem can happen if the image (or one of the images preceeding it) was declared inside of a \label{} (i.e. in the .aux file): 'convert with system call' has no access to the main aux file.
   Possible solutions in this case:
   a) Try using 'mode=list and make',
   b) Issue the externalization command 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "P-figure_crossref0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{P}\input{P}"' *manually* (also check the preceeding externalized images, perhaps the file name sequence is not correct).
   Repeat: the resulting image was EMPTY, your attention is required .
```

In your example, I issued the command shown in (b) and it worked.

See the pgfplots manual for details about the cause of this problem.

1. As we have seen, the default conversion mode fails. But if `force remake` is in effect, the default conversion mode is *always* applied, even if you followed step (b). Thus, there is the choice to deactivate `force remake` or to use `mode=list and make`.

Comment: I am not sure how current this answer is, and how current it is supposed to be, but I noticed something that I think is worth putting in a comment here. When you have externalized plot graphics *and* externalized `\ref`-icons of plot references into those graphics, `list and make` does *not* put the icon jobs into the list after the first run of `Xlatex`. One has to run `Xlatex; make; Xlatex; make; ...` to get all of these. (Is this intentional? I'm using pgfplots 1.12.1 with TikZ 3.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

The quick and easy solution is to temporarily disable the externalization with `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable`.
Therefore one should write:

```
\tikzexternaldisable
\ref{named}
\tikzexternalenable
```

instead of simply

```
\ref{named}
```

Where `named` is the label corresponding to

```
legend to name = named,
```

inside the options of the `axis` environment, as specified in the section  *4.9.7
Legends Outside Of an Axis* of the `pgfplots` manual.