# Plots from externalized TikZ are rotated

Tags: tikz-pgf, input, tikz-external, matlab

I just found out about `tikzexternalize` and I love it - well, almost. This is my situation: I have done simulations in Matlab and used 
[matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz)
 
to get the plots from Matlab into my `.tex` document. This worked fine until I reached the point where I got an error because I ran out of memory. Then I found the externalization stuff. When I finally got it to work, my plots were all rotated 90 degrees clockwise. Why? When I just do a simple plot inside my main file, it works fine, so why does it not work for those input files?

This is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode = list and make,optimize=false,
prefix=Bilder/] 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
xlabel=\hspace*{-1.0 ex}\raisebox{-1.5 ex}{$x$}, 
ylabel=\hspace*{-2.5 ex}\raisebox{-2.5 ex}{$y$}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{Bilder/mymatlabfig.tikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where `mymatlabfig.tikz` comes from the `matlab2tikz` script:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.2.3.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2012, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% 
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
% 
% 
% 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
view={0}{90},
width=0.5\textwidth,
height=0.394354838709677\textwidth,
scale only axis,
xmin=-4, xmax=4,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
legend style={align=left}]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid
]
coordinates{
(-3.14159265358979,-1.22464679914735e-16)(-3.0133643820147,-0.127877161684506)(-2.88513611043961,-0.253654583909507)(-2.75690783886451,-0.375267004879374)(-2.62867956728942,-0.490717552003938)(-2.50045129571433,-0.598110530491216)(-2.37222302413923,-0.695682550603486)(-2.24399475256414,-0.78183148246803)(-2.11576648098904,-0.855142763005346)(-1.98753820941395,-0.914412623015812)(-1.85930993783886,-0.958667853036661)(-1.73108166626376,-0.98718178341445)(-1.60285339468867,-0.999486216200688)(-1.47462512311358,-0.995379112949198)(-1.34639685153848,-0.974927912181824)(-1.21816857996339,-0.93846842204976)(-1.0899403083883,-0.886599306373)(-0.961712036813202,-0.820172254596956)(-0.833483765238108,-0.740277997075315)(-0.705255493663015,-0.648228395307789)(-0.577027222087921,-0.545534901210549)(-0.448798950512828,-0.433883739117558)(-0.320570678937734,-0.315108218023621)(-0.192342407362641,-0.191158628701372)(-0.064114135787547,-0.0640702199807131)(0.064114135787547,0.0640702199807131)(0.192342407362641,0.
191158628701372)(0.320570678937734,0.315108218023621)(0.448798950512828,0.433883739117558)(0.577027222087921,0.545534901210549)(0.705255493663015,0.648228395307788)(0.833483765238108,0.740277997075315)(0.961712036813202,0.820172254596956)(1.0899403083883,0.886599306373)(1.21816857996339,0.938468422049761)(1.34639685153848,0.974927912181824)(1.47462512311358,0.995379112949198)(1.60285339468867,0.999486216200688)(1.73108166626376,0.98718178341445)(1.85930993783886,0.958667853036661)(1.98753820941395,0.914412623015812)(2.11576648098904,0.855142763005346)(2.24399475256414,0.78183148246803)(2.37222302413923,0.695682550603487)(2.50045129571432,0.598110530491217)(2.62867956728942,0.490717552003938)(2.75690783886451,0.375267004879374)(2.88513611043961,0.253654583909507)(3.0133643820147,0.127877161684506)(3.14159265358979,1.22464679914735e-16) 
};
\addlegendentry{sin x};

\addplot [
color=green!50!black,
solid
]
coordinates{
(-3.14159265358979,-1)(-3.0133643820147,-0.991790013823246)(-2.88513611043961,-0.967294863039029)(-2.75690783886451,-0.926916757346022)(-2.62867956728942,-0.871318704123389)(-2.50045129571433,-0.801413621867957)(-2.37222302413923,-0.718349350097727)(-2.24399475256414,-0.623489801858733)(-2.11576648098904,-0.518392568310525)(-1.98753820941395,-0.404783343122394)(-1.85930993783886,-0.284527586631032)(-1.73108166626376,-0.159599895033379)(-1.60285339468867,-0.0320515775716552)(-1.47462512311358,0.0960230259076819)(-1.34639685153848,0.222520933956314)(-1.21816857996339,0.345365054421308)(-1.0899403083883,0.462538290240835)(-0.961712036813202,0.57211666012217)(-0.833483765238108,0.672300890261317)(-0.705255493663015,0.761445958369134)(-0.577027222087921,0.838088104891841)(-0.448798950512828,0.900968867902419)(-0.320570678937734,0.949055747010669)(-0.192342407362641,0.981559156991065)(-0.064114135787547,0.997945392750336)(0.064114135787547,0.997945392750336)(0.192342407362641,0.981559156991065)(0.320570678937734,
0.949055747010669)(0.448798950512828,0.900968867902419)(0.577027222087921,0.838088104891841)(0.705255493663015,0.761445958369135)(0.833483765238108,0.672300890261317)(0.961712036813202,0.57211666012217)(1.0899403083883,0.462538290240835)(1.21816857996339,0.345365054421307)(1.34639685153848,0.222520933956314)(1.47462512311358,0.0960230259076814)(1.60285339468867,-0.032051577571655)(1.73108166626376,-0.159599895033379)(1.85930993783886,-0.284527586631032)(1.98753820941395,-0.404783343122394)(2.11576648098904,-0.518392568310525)(2.24399475256414,-0.623489801858733)(2.37222302413923,-0.718349350097727)(2.50045129571432,-0.801413621867956)(2.62867956728942,-0.871318704123389)(2.75690783886451,-0.926916757346022)(2.88513611043961,-0.967294863039029)(3.0133643820147,-0.991790013823246)(3.14159265358979,-1) 
};
\addlegendentry{cos x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

The result is a rotated plot. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Why `list and make`? Without it, it compiles perfectly (_x_ to the right, _y_ going up).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, thanks for the suggestion, but it does not work. I used "list and make" to have references, but leaving it out does not result in a correct plot, either. There is a greater issue somewhere...

By the way, the x and y are placed correctly, but the plot is wrong, it is supposed to be a sine and a cosine...

Comment: I do not know about `list and make` to use it successfully. In my `list and make`-less compilation [it looks like sine and cosine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tdLLU.png), though.

Comment: OK, you're right - I forgot to delete the file... So now I can have correct plots, but no references? When I add a label to the figure and use \ref I get an error and no reference. With list and make referencing works, but the plots are wrong. Why?

Comment: In fact, without "list and make" I always get an error (even without labels and \ref) complaining about a missing -shell-escape option, but I used it...

Comment: Forget the last post, moving '-shell-escape' to first position did the trick. But I still cannot have references. I tried [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37471/pgfplots-externalization-and-legend-referencing), but it does not work for me...

Comment: adding 'invoke before crossref tikzpicture={\tikzexternaldisable}, invoke after crossref tikzpicture={\tikzexternalenable},' to \pgfplotset did the trick. I still don't understand why 'list and make' fails so miserably in creating a correct plot, but I guess this works fine for me.

Comment: @schnupsi I have tried to insert a `\label` into you picture and a `\ref` into the main document - and it works with `list and make` (without disabling the externalization). Note that you have to compile multiple times to get the references right (as usual in TeX). If it does not work after multiple runs, you may want to create a minimal example and post a bug report for pgfplots and/or TikZ. The bug report should be generated with `\listfiles` as first line in your main file.