# How to reuse the plotmark styles from PGFPlots outside the tikzpicture environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In a figure caption or in the main text I want to reuse the style of the plotmarks or the combination of line and symbol as in the figure legend. As I did not find a command to reuse the legend image I tried to draw the plotmark with the same properties but it seems that the syntax must be changed?

An illustration of what I have in mind:
[image]

The corresponding code:
        \documentclass{article}

```
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} 
    \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks} 

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)},anchor=north west},] 

    \addplot+[blue,
                        mark options={solid,fill=.!30!white},
                        mark=*,] 
                        coordinates {(1,1) (2,3) (3,5)};
                        \addlegendentry{$H \parallel c$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 

    Reusing plot mark style in figure caption does not work:
    \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\node[blue,mark options={solid,fill=.!30!white}] at (0,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
    \end{document}
```

Is there any way to easily redraw the legend image or the plotmark outside of the pgfplot axis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what the `\label` and `\ref` functionality of PGFPlots is great for: You add `\label{<label name>}` after the plot you want to show in your legend, and use `\ref{<label name>}` at the place where you want to show the legend image:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} 
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)},anchor=north west},] 

\addplot+[blue,
                    mark options={solid,fill=.!30!white},
                    mark=*,] 
                    coordinates {(1,1) (2,3) (3,5)};
                    \addlegendentry{$H \parallel c$};
                    \label{firstplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

Reusing plot mark style in figure caption does not work:
\ref{firstplot}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, that is very nice. I overlooked this part of the documentation. At first it did not work with externalization but after some fiddling even that runs smoothly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Alexander: Could you please provide your fixes, that `\label` and `\ref` works with externalization?

Comment: @HenriMenke: Take a look at the comments and the answer to [pgfplots: externalization and legend referencing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37471/pgfplots-externalization-and-legend-referencing). There are two ways of getting it to work: Either by disabling the externalization locally for the `\ref` command, or by using the `list-and-make` externalization mode.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I locally disabled the externalization, similar to the comments Jake linked to. This works without further changes to my setup and does not cause any negative side-effects.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been struggling with this some times and then chose to remove all the `label`-`ref`-constructs. Your answer is great!