# How to add PGF plot marker separately to document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Say I have some PGF plot, which uses some custom plot markers, for instance:

```
\newcommand{\scaleofcirc}{0.85}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{manualcirc}
{
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgfplotmarksize*\scaleofcirc}{0pt}}
\pgfpatharc{0}{360}{\pgfplotmarksize*\scaleofcirc}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepathqfill
}
```

For some reason, I want to typeset the plot marker separately, so not as part of a plot, in a latex document. It should be typeset as part of some text.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `\pgfuseplotmark{<name>}`

Comment: That works, but is not exactly what I want. I would like the plotmark to become part of the text in a natural way; it should be centered as if it were a letter, and preferably also have the size of a letter.

Comment: If you're not inside a `tikzpicture`, you can use the command Gonzalo mentioned like so: `\tikz \pgfuseplotmark{*};`. Maybe you're looking for something like the PGFPlots `\label` and `\ref` functionality, though: [How to reuse the plotmark styles from pgfplots?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97592/how-to-reuse-the-plotmark-styles-from-pgfplots) That way, the plot mark style will be synchronised with the style of the plot in the `axis` environment (if you change the color, say).

Comment: @Jake That is exactly what I need. I actually spend quite a while to find out if someone posted my question allready. But now it appears that is is a duplicate after all. Sorry

Comment: It might be a good idea to add something like "outside the plot" to the title of that question you cited. It didn't show up when I was searching for it, while I feel it is a crucial part of the question.

Comment: @willem: Good idea about the title. It's really hard to find questions on this site. Even when I *know* there's a similar question, I still have trouble digging it up. Google usually does a much better job than the search bar on the site itself.