# pgfplots: Legends in multiple y-axis plot overlapping

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am trying to add a legend for two plots on two different y-axes, however they are overlapping each other and each one is being written in its own box. I would like for both of them to share a single box and not overlap each other.

Most of the examples I have seen for creating the legend assume that all series happen within a single `axis` environment, but creating a second y-axis requires me to also create a second `axis` environment, and I am guessing that's where I run into trouble.

Here's a MWE. What am I overlooking?

```
\documentclass{article}

% UNITS
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}

% GRAPHICS
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
     scale only axis,
     scaled x ticks=base 10:3,
     axis y line*=left,
     xmin=0, xmax=0.06,
     ymin=0, ymax=80,
     xlabel=$Q/\si{\metre\cubed\per\second}$,
     ylabel=$H/\si{\metre}$]
     \addplot[smooth,mark=x,blue] 
     coordinates{
          (0,68.6)
          (0.0148,72) 
          (0.0295,68.6)
          (0.0441,53.4)
          (0.059,22.8) 
        };
%        \addlegendentry{$H$}
        \legend{$H$}
      \end{axis}

      \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis,
        scaled x ticks=base 10:3
        /pgf/number format/sci subscript,
        axis y line*=right,
        axis x line=none,
        xmin=0, xmax=0.06,
        ymin=0, ymax=100,
        ylabel=$\eta/\si{\percent}$]
        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,red] 
        coordinates{
          (0,0)
          (0.0148,48) 
          (0.0295,66)
          (0.0441,66)
          (0.059,45.0) 
        };
 %      \addlegendentry{$\eta$}
        \legend{$\eta$}
       \end{axis}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but if you're open to putting the legend in the caption, you can do so by adding `\label{plot:one}` immediately after the first `\addplot ...;` and then `\ref{plot:one}` in the caption.

Comment: Oddly enough, this does not work for me. I looked up the syntax and proper use in the `pgfplots` manual, and still, nothing. All I get is an unresolved-reference error.

Comment: It worked fine for me- see [Jake's answer to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20926/tikz-legend-in-caption). The problem with your current approach is that the legends are overlaying each other. Another work around is to position the separate legends in different locations in the graph- this may be a good idea, as it might help the reader determine which y-axis to look at. You can add `legend pos=north west` to the first `axis` environment, for example, so that `\eta` is in the top left, and `H` is in the top right

Comment: I figured out what was going wrong here, though not how to fix it. I tested the plot in an `article` class, but my document is a `tufte-handout` class, that places the captions in the margin. In the `article` class it works as expected, but in the `tufte-handout` even when I tried protecting the `\ref` as recommended in the pgfmanual, it still did not work. I like the idea of placing each serie's legend close to it's axis. I'll try it.

Comment: It works well, but doesn't seem to suit this particular plot well.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could alter the legend of the second plot "by hand" by using `\addlegendimage{<plot options>} \addlegendentry{<plot title>}` after the second plot. You can access the `<plot options>` of the first plot by assigning a `\label{<name>}` to it and using the key `/pgfplots/refstyle=<name>` in your `\addlegendimage` command:

[image]

---

Another option would be to label the plots directly. Since pgfplots version 1.5.1, you can place nodes a specified length along the plot by including a `node [pos=<fraction>] {}` in the `\addplot` command.

[image]

---

Depending on how you're going to use the graph, you could also consider colouring the axis to match the plots. This will be problematic if you need to print the document in black and white, but in a presentation, this might be more elegant than forcing the audience's eyes from the plot line to the legend and then to the y axes in order to match plot and axis.

I've defined a style `y axis style=<colour>` that simultaneously sets the colour for `y axis line style`, `y tick style`, `yticklabel style` and `ylabel style`, so you can just call `y axis style=red!75!black` to set all the elements belonging to the y axis to that colour.

[image]

---

### One legend for both axes

```
\documentclass{article}

    % UNITS
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}

    % GRAPHICS
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis,
    scaled x ticks=base 10:3,
    xmin=0, xmax=0.06
}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=left,
  ymin=0, ymax=80,
  xlabel=$Q/\si{\m\cubed\per\s}$,
  ylabel=$H/\si{\m}$,
]
\addplot[smooth,mark=x,blue] 
  coordinates{
    (0,68.6)
    (0.0148,72) 
    (0.0295,68.6)
    (0.0441,53.4)
    (0.059,22.8) 
}; \label{Hplot}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line=none,
  ymin=0, ymax=100,
  ylabel=$\eta/\si{\percent}$
]
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Hplot}\addlegendentry{$H$}
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,red] 
  coordinates{
    (0,0)
    (0.0148,48) 
    (0.0295,66)
    (0.0441,66)
    (0.059,45.0) 
}; \addlegendentry{$\eta$}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Plots directly labeled

```
\documentclass{article}

    % UNITS
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}

    % GRAPHICS
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis,
    scaled x ticks=base 10:3,
    xmin=0, xmax=0.06
}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=left,
  ymin=0, ymax=80,
  xlabel=$Q/\si{\m\cubed\per\s}$,
  ylabel=$H/\si{\m}$
]
\addplot[smooth,mark=x,blue] 
  coordinates{
    (0,68.6)
    (0.0148,72) 
    (0.0295,68.6)
    (0.0441,53.4)
    (0.059,22.8) 
} node [pos=0.04,anchor=north, text=black] {$H$}; \label{Hplot}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line=none,
  ymin=0, ymax=100,
  ylabel=$\eta/\si{\percent}$
]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,red] 
  coordinates{
    (0,0)
    (0.0148,48) 
    (0.0295,66)
    (0.0441,66)
    (0.059,45.0) 
} node [pos=0.9,anchor=south west, text=black] {$\eta$};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Axis colours match plot colours

```
\documentclass{article}

    % UNITS
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}

    % GRAPHICS
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis,
    scaled x ticks=base 10:3,
    xmin=0, xmax=0.06,
    y axis style/.style={
        yticklabel style=#1,
        ylabel style=#1,
        y axis line style=#1,
        ytick style=#1
   }
}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=left,
  y axis style=blue!75!black,
  ymin=0, ymax=80,
  xlabel=$Q/\si{\m\cubed\per\s}$,
  ylabel=$H/\si{\m}$
]
\addplot[smooth,mark=x,blue] 
  coordinates{
    (0,68.6)
    (0.0148,72) 
    (0.0295,68.6)
    (0.0441,53.4)
    (0.059,22.8) 
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line=none,
  ymin=0, ymax=100,
  ylabel=$\eta/\si{\percent}$,
  y axis style=red!75!black
]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,red] 
  coordinates{
    (0,0)
    (0.0148,48) 
    (0.0295,66)
    (0.0441,66)
    (0.059,45.0) 
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Nice! I tried this approach with `\label` and `\ref` but failed. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: I'm fine with doing things "by hand" as long as they work, and this worked just fine! Would it be possible to get it to work with `\label` and `\ref`. I noticed that it is position-dependent. I have another plot like this with an extra series in the first `axis` environment, and if I place the `\addlegendimage{red,mark=*}{$\eta$}` after that other series, the legend-image displays that series' style and not the one specified between the braces. The simple solution was to place the legend before that second `\addplot` in the first `axis` environment.

Comment: @cmhughes: You could use `\addlegendimage{legend image code/.code=\ref{<name>}}`, which kind of works, but there are some issues with the alignment (adding a `yshift=-0.5ex` seems to work, but isn't very elegant). Instead of using `\ref` directly, you can access just the plot options associated with a labeled plot by calling the key `/pgfplots/refstyle=<name>`. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Ricardo: I've edited my answer to use the `\label` approach. You still need to be careful with the order you're calling `\addlegendimage` and `\addplot`, though: Each time you call one of those commands, the current plot style is added to a a list, and the instances of `\addlegendentry` just use the plot styles in the order they are found in that list. In other words, `\addlegendentry` doesn't care whether it's called directly after `\addplot` or `\addlegendimage`, it just goes by the list.

Comment: The One legend for both axes example (actually presumably all, thats just what I've tried) does not work properly for me.
The y axis numbers are drawn correctly left and right.
The y axis label however, ist drawn on the left two times above each other.

Comment: Found the solution:
  ylabel near ticks,
  yticklabel pos=right,
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63812/pgfplot-with-y-axis-only-on-the-right-hand-side