# PgfPlot with Y-axis only on the right hand side

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw graph similar to the one below with the Y-axis only on the RHS.

[image: A graph with the Y-axis only on the right hand side.]

The following MWE produces something close the desired result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[ylabel=Y-Axis, xlabel=X-Axis
, xmin=2, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=12, clip=false, axis y line*=right]
    \foreach \blah in {0.9,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01,0.005}{
        \addplot[mark=none, domain=2:10, thick] {-ln(\blah/x^2)/ln(x)} node [pos=0,left] {$c_2=$}; %Varying c_2 values
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

as this image shows:

[image: Graph showing the Y-axis almost on the right hand side, but the line on the left has disappeared]

The y-axis label has not moved to the right and the box line on the left has disappeared entirely.

Any thoughts on how to make things right and get a y-axis on the right-hand side and a box line on the left-hand side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Replace `axis y line*=right` with  `ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right` (Thanks Jake):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[
        ylabel=Y-Axis, xlabel=X-Axis, 
        xmin=2, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=12, clip=false, 
        %axis y line*=right% replaced this option with:
        ylabel near ticks, yticklabel pos=right
        ]
    \foreach \blah in {0.9,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01,0.005}{
        \addplot[mark=none, domain=2:10, thick] {-ln(\blah/x^2)/ln(x)} node [pos=0,left] {$c_2=$}; %Varying c_2 values
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Do you know how I can get a solid line on the left-hand side of the box?

Comment: Perfect @Jake, thanks. Feel free to edit Peter's answer or write one up of your own.