# Pgfplots legend style marker size

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have the following plot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
  xlabel={\tiny X},
  ylabel={\tiny Y},
  xmin=0, xmax=5,
  ymin=0, ymax=18,
  minor x tick num=4,
  minor y tick num=4,
  ytick={0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18},
  y tick label style={
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
          fixed,
          fixed zerofill,
          precision=2,
      /tikz/.cd,
      font=\tiny},
  x tick label style={font=\tiny},
  every x tick/.style={color=black, thin},
  every y tick/.style={color=black, thin},
  xtick pos=left,
  ytick pos=left,
  axis on top,
  width=5cm,
  height=5cm,
  legend style={mark options={scale=5.0}, at={(0.97,0.03)}, anchor=south east},
  clip mode=individual
  ]
  \addplot+[
  color=red,
  solid,
  line width=1.0pt,
  mark size=1.8pt,
  mark=star,
  mark options={solid, line width=0.5pt},
  error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]
  plot coordinates {
  (0, 1)
  (1, 2)
  (2, 4)
  (3, 8)
  (4, 16)
  };
  \addlegendentry{My plot};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

And I am trying to change the scale/size of the markers inside the legend.
I have been looking around for a while now and could not find a solution.
The only solution I found was a thread where someone wanted to reduce the scale of the markers in the legend and the suggested solution was to add

```
    legend style={mark options={scale=0.5}
```

I tried to use that to increase the scale, but it still doesn't do anything to my final output.
I also did try:

```
    legend style={mark options={size=5pt}
```

and

```
    legend style={mark size=5pt}
```

without success.

I am running:
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
Package: pgfplots 2015/01/31 v1.12 Data Visualization (1.12)

Does anyone have a suggestion why it would not work, or any other solution to increase the mark size in the legend?

Comment: Weirdly enough, it works if you use `legend style={mark size=5pt}` and comment out the `mark size=1.8pt` line in the `\addplot` options. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89797/pgfplots-selectively-reducing-marker-size-in-the-legend

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That does work. Unfortunately, now the mark size in the plot is too small. I am guessing its just the default value now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `legend image post style={scale=0.5},`. For details, consult [page 261](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=261) of `pgfplots` [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) (version 1.17).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
  xlabel={\tiny X},
  ylabel={\tiny Y},
  xmin=0, xmax=5,
  ymin=0, ymax=18,
  minor x tick num=4,
  minor y tick num=4,
  ytick={0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18},
  y tick label style={
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
          fixed,
          fixed zerofill,
          precision=2,
      /tikz/.cd,
      font=\tiny},
  x tick label style={font=\tiny},
  every x tick/.style={color=black, thin},
  every y tick/.style={color=black, thin},
  xtick pos=left,
  ytick pos=left,
  axis on top,
  width=5cm,
  height=5cm,
  legend image post style={scale=0.5},  %%% <--- here
  legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)}, anchor=south east},
  clip mode=individual
  ]
  \addplot+[
  color=red,
  solid,
  line width=1.0pt,
  mark=star,  
  mark options={mark size=4pt,solid, line width=0.5pt}, %% make size 4pt for demo
  error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]
  plot coordinates {
  (0, 1)
  (1, 2)
  (2, 4)
  (3, 8)
  (4, 16)
  };
  \addlegendentry{My plot};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use `forget plot` in the `\addplot+` options and the add

```
\addlegendimage{red,line width=1.0pt,,mark=star,mark options={mark size=2pt,solid, line width=0.5pt}};
  \addlegendentry{My plot};
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly.
I would have never though of looking at the "legend image post style".