# Reference of plot not resolved

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, cross-referencing, labels

The label of the first plot (added by \addlegendimage) appears in default black after two compilations which indicates that the reference of the first plot is not being resolved. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,float}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}



\begin{filecontents*}{curvas_tension_DC_y_vel_desacoplamiento_OWB_Hor.csv}
t;v_DC;vel_DCPM;vel_AFPM
0;0;0;0
0.5;0.5;1.25;0.125
1;1;5;1
1.5;1.5;11.25;3.375
2;2;20;8
2.5;2.5;31.25;15.625
3;3;45;27
3.5;3.5;61.25;42.875
4;4;80;64
4.5;4.5;101.25;91.125
5;5;125;125
5.5;5.5;151.25;166.375
6;6;180;216
6.5;6.5;211.25;274.625
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymin=0, ymax=6.75,
xmin=0, xmax=6.75,
grid,
xtick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5},
ytick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5},
axis y line*=left, % the '*' avoids arrow heads
xlabel={$t$ [s]},
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel={$v_{fuente}$ [V]},
ylabel near ticks,
width=\textwidth, 
height=0.7\textwidth,
]

\addplot[ultra thick,violet!17] table[x=t, y=v_DC,col sep=semicolon]{curvas_tension_DC_y_vel_desacoplamiento_OWB_Hor.csv}; \label{plot_one}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
ymin=0, ymax=325,
xmin=0, xmax=6.75,
ytick={0,50,100,150,200,250,300},
hide x axis,
axis y line*=right,
ylabel={Velocidad [rpm]},
ylabel near ticks,
width=\textwidth, 
height=0.7\textwidth,
]

\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}\addlegendentry{$v_{fuente}$}

\addplot[no markers,teal] table[x=t, y=vel_DCPM,col sep=semicolon]{curvas_tension_DC_y_vel_desacoplamiento_OWB_Hor.csv};
\addlegendentry{$n _{m \, in}$};

\addplot[no markers,orange] table[x=t, y=vel_AFPM,col sep=semicolon]{curvas_tension_DC_y_vel_desacoplamiento_OWB_Hor.csv};
\addlegendentry{$n _{m \, out}$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[Here](https://file.io/iGVEwmCUbW1Q) you can find the .csv file.

For this I followed the example in the accepted answer in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198997/pgfplots-two-y-axis-with-three-plots-and-one-legend).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it is your **18th question** and it seems there is still confusion about MWE etc., please consider these three resources to familiarize yourself with this site: **(1)** https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, **(2)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour, and **(3)** https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 (MWE).

Comment: Sorry, @Dr.ManuelKuehner. I will always provide an MWE from now on.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this makes it much easier to reproduce the issue. On that note maybe one further improvement: instead of linking to an external site for the csv file, maybe you can make the file smaller with just a few rows and columns that are needed to reproduce the problem, and then add the contents of the csv as a second code block in the question? External links can stop working at any time, and they are also a security risk.

Comment: After adding the missing `\usepackage{pgpflots}` and removing the erroneous `\pgfplotsset{tikz}` I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNZpA.png, so seems like your code works fine?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. the code that I updated does not show (to me at least) the label of plot_one in violet, but in black. Even after more than 2 compilations.

Comment: The code exactly as is now would throw an error because you use `\pgfplotsset` before `\usepackage{pgfplots}`. Edit: and another error because of the `\FloatBarrier`.

Comment: Is there any information in the log file about errors, warnings or unresolved references?

Comment: @Marijn Yes. This warning: LaTeX Warning: External picture `main-figure1' contains undefined references o
n input line 71.
===== The previous system call resulted in undefined references inside of the o
utput file. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========

Comment: That warning is generated when you use `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` and there is a problem somewhere, but this library is not loaded in the code you show here. Just to be sure: do you get that warning from this code (of course after correcting both errors that  
Torbjørn mentioned, i.e., moving `\pgfplotsset` one line down and removing `\FloatBarrier`)?

Comment: @Marijn No, \usepgfplotslibrary{external} must be added. What I copied here is a fragment of other much more longer code.

Comment: Copying fragments is not really the idea of an MWE, for the exact reason you are seeing here: the code as provided now leads to the correct output (with a few unrelated changes), while your real problem is elsewhere (i.e., with external figures). So please provide an MWE that actually reproduces the issue, otherwise it is difficult to help you further.

Comment: I just saw the edit, however you did not fix the two other errors mentioned (the position of `\pgfplotsset` and `\FloatBarrier`). This means the code _still_ doesn't reproduce the issue. Please take care to **test** the MWE before posting/editing it.

Comment: @Marijn I compiled on Overleaf the code I edited and it gave no error. Why does the use of \FloatBarrier lead to error?

Comment: `\FloatBarrier` is a command from the `placeins` package, that you didn't load in the MWE. Overleaf ignores errors by default, which often leads to incorrect output but some output is always shown if possible - maybe you missed the error message because of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140326/discussion-between-el-maxx-and-marijn).