Tikz: Grouped Plot with Secondary y-axis
I have been working quite some time on a grouped error bar plot, but I've hit a wall: one of the variables (Variable 2) comes from a logistic regression, so its value/coefficient isn't directly comparable to the others. The scale difference between the values corresponding to 'Variable 2' and 'Variables 1 and 3' results in tiny error bars for the latter, complicating interpretation. To fix this, I want to add a secondary y-axis on the right side of the plot just for Variable 2. Would that be possible?
The plot that I have created right now looks as follows:

The code to generate the plot is given below.
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta} % added arrows.meta
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{buy_color}{RGB}{0, 102, 204} % blue
\definecolor{sell_color}{RGB}{255, 51, 51} % red
\definecolor{all_color}{RGB}{0, 153, 0} % green


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
  error bars/.cd,
    x dir=none,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my plots,
        group size=1 by 3,
        vertical sep=1.5cm
    },
    width=12cm,
    height=6cm,
    tick pos=left,
    tick align=outside,
    yticklabel pos=left,
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    ylabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend pos=north west,
]

\nextgroupplot[
    xlabel=Variables (Panel A),
    ylabel=Value,
    xtick={1,...,3},
    xticklabels={Variable 1,Variable 2, Variable 3},
]
  \addplot [mark=*,color=buy_color,only marks] table [x expr={\thisrow{x}-0.1}, y=y, y error=ey] {
    x y ey
    1 -0.057 -0.022
    2 -0.99 -0.28
    3 0.042 0.11
  };
  \addlegendentry{Buy}
  
  \addplot [mark=*,color=sell_color,only marks] table [x expr={\thisrow{x}+0.1}, y=y, y error=ey] {
    x y ey
    1 -0.10 -0.07
    2 -0.52 0.26
    3 0.022 0.10
  };
  \addlegendentry{Sell}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Since tikz/pgf questions with complete examples tend to get first answers quickly, I'm guessing I may not be the only one who doesn't understand this question :(.

The scale difference between the values corresponding to 'Variable 2' and 'Variables 1 and 3' results in tiny error bars for the latter, complicating interpretation. To fix this, I want to add a secondary y-axis on the right side of the plot just for Variable 2.

Essentially similar to this post, but I have not been able to work it out:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198997/pgfplots-two-y-axis-with-three-plots-and-one-legend
I want the axis on the right only to be used for the buy/sell values for 'Variable 2'

So you want to apply the accepted answer's method there to your code here? That's my answer, apparently ....

Indeed, I am struggling to apply the accepted answer's method to my own code.

My answer there needed updating to compile without error, but I'm not sure it is applicable here because I'm not sure how to transfer it to a groupplot. In the other answer, I basically just draw one graph over the other. They're just superimposed. That works because, for example, they're set up to have precisely the same size on the page. But that's not the case here and I'm not really sure how much sense it makes in this case. Even in the other one, it seems confusing to a reader.

Hi!  I try to understand what you are looking for.  1) You have numbers comming from two sources.  2) There is a scaling factor between them. 3) You want to represent this scaling factor by adding a second y-axis that will integrate the scaling.  If these are correct, then why don't you modify the numbers coming from one of your sources accordingly, before using them?

Hi Daniel! Regarding those coefficients; variable 1 and 3's are from a simple linear regressions, but variable 2's is from a logistic regression. I'm not sure if we can directly scale the coefficients of a logistic regression coefficient such that it is in line with that of a linear regression. Hence, I was considering adding a secondary y-axis to the right of the figure specifically for the coefficient of variable 2.

In case the groupplot is not required, how about this:
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{buy_color}{RGB}{0, 102, 204} % blue
\definecolor{sell_color}{RGB}{255, 51, 51} % red
\definecolor{all_color}{RGB}{0, 153, 0} % green

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{%
        error bars/.cd,
        x dir=none,
        y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=12cm,
        height=6cm,
        tick pos=left,
        tick align=outside,
        yticklabel pos=left,
        yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        ylabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend pos=south east,
        xlabel=Variables (Panel A),
        ylabel=Value,
        xtick={1,...,3},
        xticklabels={Variable 1,Variable 2, Variable 3},
        ]
        \addplot [mark=*,color=buy_color,only marks, x filter/.expression={x == 2 ? nan : x-0.1}] table [y error=ey] {%
            x y ey
            1 -0.057 -0.022
            2 -0.99 -0.28
            3 0.042 0.11
        };
        \addlegendentry{Buy}
        \addplot [mark=*,color=sell_color,only marks, x filter/.expression={x == 2 ? nan : x+0.1}] table [y error=ey] {%
            x y ey
            1 -0.10 -0.07
            2 -0.52 0.26
            3 0.022 0.10
        };
        \addlegendentry{Sell}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=12cm,
        height=6cm,
        tick pos=right,
        tick align=outside,
        yticklabel pos=right,
        ylabel=Value (Variable 2),
        xtick=\empty,
        xticklabels=\empty,
        xmin=1, xmax=3,
        ]
        \addplot [mark=*,color=buy_color,only marks, x filter/.expression={x == 2 ? x-0.1 : nan}] table [y error=ey] {%
            x y ey
            1 -0.057 -0.022
            2 -0.99 -0.28
            3 0.042 0.11
        };
        \addplot [mark=*,color=sell_color,only marks, x filter/.expression={x == 2 ? x+0.1 : nan}] table [y error=ey] {%
            x y ey
            1 -0.10 -0.07
            2 -0.52 0.26
            3 0.022 0.10
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


If the groupplot is needed, an approach would be:
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{buy_color}{RGB}{0, 102, 204} % blue
\definecolor{sell_color}{RGB}{255, 51, 51} % red
\definecolor{all_color}{RGB}{0, 153, 0} % green

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{%
        error bars/.cd,
        x dir=none,
        y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
    \begin{groupplot}[%
        group style={%
            group name=my plots,
            group size=1 by 3,
            vertical sep=1.5cm
        },
        width=12cm,
        height=6cm,
        tick pos=left,
        tick align=outside,
        yticklabel pos=left,
        yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        ylabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend pos=north west,
        ]
        \nextgroupplot[
        xlabel=Variables (Panel A),
        ylabel=Value,
        xtick={1,...,3},
        xticklabels={Variable 1,Variable 2, Variable 3},
        ]
        \addplot [mark=*,color=buy_color, only marks, x filter/.expression={x == 2? nan : x-0.1}] table [y error=ey] {%
            x y ey
            1 -0.057 -0.022
            2 -0.99 -0.28
            3 0.042 0.11
        };
        \addlegendentry{Buy}
        \addplot [mark=*,color=sell_color,only marks, x filter/.expression={x == 2? nan : x+0.1}] table [y error=ey] {%
            x y ey
            1 -0.10 -0.07
            2 -0.52 0.26
            3 0.022 0.10
        };
        \addlegendentry{Sell}
        \nextgroupplot[
        ]
        \addplot [red, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {x^3};
    \end{groupplot}
    \begin{groupplot}[%
        group style={%
            group name=my plots,
            group size=1 by 3,
            vertical sep=1.5cm
        },
        width=12cm,
        height=6cm,
        ]
        \nextgroupplot[
        tick pos=right,
        tick align=outside,
        yticklabel pos=right,
        ylabel=Value (Variable 2),
        xtick=\empty,
        xticklabels=\empty,
        xmin=1, xmax=3,
        ]
        \addplot [mark=*,color=buy_color,only marks, x filter/.expression={x == 2? x-0.1 : nan}] table [y error=ey] {%
            x y ey
            1 -0.057 -0.022
            2 -0.99 -0.28
            3 0.042 0.11
        };
        \addplot [mark=*,color=sell_color,only marks, x filter/.expression={x == 2? x+0.1 : nan}] table [y error=ey] {%
            x y ey
            1 -0.10 -0.07
            2 -0.52 0.26
            3 0.022 0.10
        };
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you for this answer! This is exactly how I want the panel to look. I created a group plot because I also have Panels B and C beneath Panel A, though I excluded them for simplicity in the illustration. Can your current implementation accommodate this configuration as well?

Updated the answer with a groupplot example. Basic idea remains the same: first draw the left axis and its plots then start all over and draw the right axis. Comment out the individual axis/groupplot environments in the answer to see what is going on.
