# PGFplot: x axis remove double value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I have a bar chart on one y axis and a line on the second y axis which both belong to the same x axis. However, the x axis shows two entries for some values (23, 42, 200). How to remove the second one in order to have only one?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={11, 23, 42, 200},
        xlabel={Datapoint},
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ymin=15, ymax=32,
        axis y line*=left,
        bar width=20pt,
        ylabel={Average Return \%},
        nodes near coords,
    ]
        \addplot[ybar, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] coordinates {
            (11,  28)
            (23,  20)
            (42,  24)
            (200, 29)
        };
    \end{axis}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis y label/.append style={rotate=180,yshift=9.5cm}}
    \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={11, 23, 42, 200},
        xlabel={Datapoint},
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ymin=15, ymax=32,
        axis y line*=right,
        ylabel={Standard Deviation \%},
        nodes near coords,
        legend style={at={(0.2,-0.2)}, anchor=north west},
    ]
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=Hplot}
        \addlegendentry{$Average\ Return$}
        \addplot[smooth, dashed, mark=*, grey] coordinates {
            (11,  25)
            (23,  28)
            (42,  19)
            (200, 21)
        };
        \addlegendentry{$Standard\ Deviation$}
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Is it required for you to have two y axes?

Comment: [Related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42697/pgfplots-legends-in-multiple-y-axis-plot-overlapping) (not duplicate, though).

Comment: There are a few unrelated errors (i.e., it's `gray`, not `grey`, and one or two others like that).

Comment: Also, for me, your "standard deviation" heading seems to have jumped off the page (also unrelated). I don't think you want the asterisk in the line `axis y line*=right`.

Comment: I would like to have two y axes as I want to show the standard deviation on the right hand side. This because more charts are created afterwards with different values.

Comment: Otherwise, I could write Percentage on the left y axis and add both plots to one y axis. But as far as my knowledge goes to amend the code, the x axis still shows the same.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to solve the problem. Typed
`xtick={11,23,42,200}` for both after the symbolic command.

Comment: I'm glad that helped you, but that isn't working for me. Good luck with your   graph!

Comment: Your answer is merely comment than answer. If you like to make it answer, than provide complete MWE which solve your problem.

Comment: A better way would be to put `xtick=data` in the options of the first axis, and `xtick=\empty` in the options of the second. That way, you don't have to hard code the values, and the labels don't get printed twice directly on top of each other.