# Manually add legend symbols in text (without \label and \ref)

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I would like to add legend symbols from `pgfplots` in my text.
I am aware of the possibility to use the `\label` and `\ref` commands
but my setup is complicated and I fear that making it work will more
time consuming than setting the small drawings manually.
I use externalization, my plots are generated with an intricate
`\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` inside a template that is used several times
in the document…

What I am looking for is a command like

```
\legendimageintext{mark=x, draw=blue}
```

that would draw a small blue dash with a cross on it, just as the
legend post of a plot with similar styles would appear.

*Note: if you want to put the legend in caption or in text, it is usually simpler to use \ref and \label as described in the pgfplots manual or [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20926/tikz-legend-in-caption). My question related to special cases where the canonical approach is not usable.*

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture should help with this?

Comment: I guess it could be indeed adapted but I fail to see how to use `\addlegendimage` without the `customlegend` environment (I do not really understand how the latter works actually).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can adapt the approach described by Christian Feuersänger in [Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture) to provide a command `\legendimageintext{mark=x, draw=blue}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

\newcommand{\addlegendimageintext}[1]{%
    \tikz {
        \begin{customlegend}[
            legend entries={\empty},
            legend style={
                draw=none,
                inner sep=0pt,
                column sep=0pt,
                nodes={inner sep=0pt}}]
        \addlegendimage{#1}
        \end{customlegend}
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\addlegendimageintext{mark=x, draw=blue} A plot

\addlegendimageintext{fill=cyan, area legend} An area plot
\end{document}
```