# Creating Tikz Legends in the Caption

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I'm having a few issues with creating a legend in the caption of an image. I've made a lot of graphs using matlab2tikz and I've externalised them to reduce my compiling time and memory usage. Consequently, I can't then use any `\label`s in the code. So I'm making a TikZ plot immediately below it and using those line styles in the caption. A MWE is displayed below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis]
\addplot [color=red,solid,forget plot]
(0,0);\label{hwplot1}
\addplot[color=brown,solid,mark=o,mark options={solid},forget plot]
(0,0);\label{Blomhoff}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I then call the label in the caption and everything works a ok. The issue that arises is that I get a brown dot at what TikZ defines at (0,0), which is the mark, and I can't find a way of getting rid of this. Is there a way I can do this? Or an alternative method of putting the legend in the caption that allows for externalization?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture

Comment: The `external` library allows references to labels in external files -- but not together with the default system call. Do you use windows or unix? Unix users can  typically use `make` to get this without any problems.

Comment: You should have a look at this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20926/tikz-legend-in-caption

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something has changed in PGFPlots since you have asked the question, but today you can just `\ref` `\label`ed `\addplot`s and you get the desired output.

Here I just wrote a dummy caption where you I `\ref`ed the labels. Hopefully this answers your question, because I am not 100% sure that I have understood it right.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.external,
    }
    \tikzexternalize[
        % prevent externalization of none named figures/plots
        % (that means that in this case the `\ref's will not be externalized)
        only named=true,
    ]
\begin{document}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{just_a_test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
                \label{hwplot1}
            \addplot+ [color=green,solid,mark=o,mark options={solid},dashed]
                coordinates {(0.1,0) (1.1,1)};
                \label{Blomhoff}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Figure~1: This is a test plot only, where \ref{hwplot1} shows a blue line
    and \ref{Blomhoff} shows a green line
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: May I ask why the images that will make the reference shall *not* be externalized?
Indeed, I use externalization very heavily and I'd prefer not to give a name to all the figures I already have.
Is there another way to do that?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin, I am not 100% sure what your question is all about. Of course you *can* also export the `\ref` pictures, but I think they are created that fast that there is no need to do so. Externalization normally is all about saving time for "expensive" figures. (As a matter of taste I like to name them accordingly so I reuse them elsewhere. There of course it is beneficial to have a clear name. And thus I don't like the generic names of non-named to be externalized figures.)

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin, so the question is, what do you mean with "Is there another way to do that?"?

Comment: I asked because externalizing all the figures (including the labels) results in one or more errors.
I wondered if another way existed to which figures can be externalized and which not, other than assigning a name and using the `only named` flag

Comment: Sorry, but commenting `only named=true` and `\tikzsetnextfilename{just_a_test}` works perfectly fine for me. I then get `minimal-figure0`, `minimal-figure_crossref0` and `minimal-figure_crossref1`. Each a DPTH, LOG, MD5, and PDF file.

Comment: ok, thanks! that's good to know.
Maybe what I experience is caused by the fact that I already have a particularly convoluted document (already had issues with externalize before)