# Colorbrewer with legend outside graph and which Colorbrewer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend

I am using Colorbrewer with PGFplots and I want the legend to be outside of the graph. The LaTeX environment is Texlive 2014.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colorbrewer cycle list=Set1,
        legend columns=-1,
        legend entries={1, 2, 3, 4},
        legend to name=values,
      ]
      \addplot {rnd};
      \addplot {rnd-1};
      \addplot {rnd-2};
      \addplot {rnd-3};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \ref{values}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I get the error `I do not know the key '/tikz/colorbrewer1'` and the legend is plotted, but colorless:

[image: Colorless legend outside of the graph]

The Colorbrewer code source comes from the [Launchpad repo](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/tikzlibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex) (posted as an answer to the question [Pre-defined color cycles à la RColorBrewer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119184/100137)).

In a very similar question to this one, [tikz legend in caption and colorbrewer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274227/100137), the answer is to use the Colorbrewer source code from the [Git repo](https://github.com/vtraag/tikz-colorbrewer).

But, I prefer the marks from the first code...

Is it possible to have the legend outside of the graph with the implementation of Colorbrewer from Launchpad, or am I better off using my custom marks for the implementation from Git?

Comment: You should consider updating your system. As of version 1.13 pgfplots has build in colorbrewer support.

Comment: That is good to hear and cuts the problem down. Unfortunately, I work in a corporate environment and updating my LaTeX distribution is not an option.