# pgfplot colorbrewer cycle

Tags: pgfplots, color

I'm trying to have nice colors for the lines of my plot, and I found that pgfplot can use a colorbrewer library. I tried to follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307878/colorbrewer-with-legend-outside-graph-and-which-colorbrewer) but it seems working with colorbrewer changed syntax at some point. Now the following code compiles fines but shows no colors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Dark2-8}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        cycle list name = Dark2-8
    ]

\addplot [mark=none] table[row sep=\\] {
-1 1\\
1 0\\
};

\addplot [mark=none] table[row sep=\\] {
-1 0\\
1 1\\
};

\addplot [mark=none] table[row sep=\\] {
-1.00 0.0000\\
-0.64 -0.3615\\
1.00 0.0000\\
};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It gives me the plot below. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: You need to use `\addplot +[mark=none]`. The `+` indicates that the options should be used in addition to the options from the cycle list. If you omit the `+`, only the options given in square brackets are used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.