# How can I divide a legend to second part?

Tags: pgfplots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [multiple legends in pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6347/multiple-legends-in-pgfplot)

I want to divide a legend to several (two) part?(like below figure)
[image]

Comment: With all respect, do you really want to do this or you just have to?

Comment: You should upvote helpful answers to the questions you've asked by clicking the upward pointing triangle next to the answers, and if an answer solved a problem, you should mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to it. This gives the answerers some reputation points, and helps others to find the best answers more quickly.

Comment: As Jake notes, you should be upvoting helpful answers. It is also good if you can take some time to look at other questions and answers which are not in response to your own and vote on those. Looking at your profile, we can see that you have (at the time of this comment) voted on nothing at all!