# Remove the title from the heading in the appendix

Tags: sectioning, appendices

I am trying to add the sequence diagrams as figures, which are in seperated file `\include{7-appendix}`, to the Appendix. They are being added but I am getting `Listings` as in the image below as heading. Is it possible to remove the word `Listings` from the heading ?

thesis.text

```
    \documentclass[
        english,
        11pt,
        twoside,
        a4paper,
        BCOR8.25mm,
        DIV10,
        headsepline,
        footsepline
    ]{scrbook}
    \include{commands}
    \begin{document}

    \selectlanguage{english}
    \frontmatter



    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Frontpage
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \input{0-titlepage.tex}

    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Inhaltsverzeichnis
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \tableofcontents
        \cleardoublepage

    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % the nromal content
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \mainmatter
        \pagestyle{fancy}

        \include{1-introduction}    

        \include{6-conclusion}

    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \appendix
        \chapter{Appendix}% 

            \listoffigures

            \listoftables

            \lstlistoflistings


      \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, height=450px]{images/trackingService}
    \caption{Sequence diagram scenario of the tracking service component}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth, height=550px]{images/accessComponent}
    \caption{Sequence diagram scenario of creating the checkbox list and starting the MapActivity}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}


        %---------------------------------------------------------------------------

        \printnomenclature

        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
        \bibliography{bibliography}

    \printindex

\end{document}
```

**commands.tex**

```
        \usepackage{a4}   
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{babel} 
        \usepackage{cite}
        \usepackage{float}      
        \usepackage{caption}    
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \usepackage{textcomp}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{epsf}
        \usepackage{color}
        \definecolor{gray}{gray}{.75}
        \usepackage[]{geometry}
        \usepackage{makeidx}
        \makeindex 
        \usepackage{cellspace}
        \usepackage{listings}
        \usepackage{subfigure}
    %Abkürzungsverzeichnis
        \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
          \let\abbrev\nomenclature
          \renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
          \setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\hsize}
          \renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
          \setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
          \makenomenclature

      \newcommand{\abk}[2]{#1\abbrev{#1}{#2}}
        \usepackage{enumitem}
        \setitemize{enumsep=-3pt}
        \setitemize{itemsep=-3pt}

        \usepackage{theorem}
        \newcounter{theorem}
        \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}


    \usepackage[bookmarks=true,
                    bookmarksopen=true,
                    bookmarksnumbered=true,
                    colorlinks=true,
                    linkcolor=black                 
                    ]
                   {hyperref}

    \usepackage{cleveref}

    \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}

    %Zitate
        \newcounter{quotectr}
        \newtheorem{myquote}[quotectr]{Zitat}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%- Layout
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

    %Call this after each chapter to avoid headlines on empty pages
        \newcommand{\chapterfin}{\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
        \newcommand{\sectionfin}{\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}





    % Fancyheaders  
        \fancyhf{} % Delete all fields
        %\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
        \fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
        \fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
        \fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage} 

    % Itemize look and feel
        \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\rule[+0.9mm]{2.7pt}{2.7pt}}
        \renewcommand{\labelitemii}{--}


        \newcommand{\eigenname}[1]  {{\em #1}}

        \newcommand{\algref}[1]{Algorithmus~\ref{alg:#1}}

        \newcommand{\quoteref}[1]{Zitat~\ref{quote:#1}}

        \renewcommand{\leq}     {\leqslant}
        \renewcommand{\geq}     {\geqslant}
        \renewcommand{\epsilon} {\varepsilon}
        \newcommand{\musec}     {$\mu sec$\xspace}
        \newcommand{\muW}       {$\mu W$\xspace}
        \newcommand{\plusminus} {$\pm $\xspace}
    \hyphenation{name-space}    
    \hyphenation{name-spaces}   
    \hyphenation{ge-samten} 


    \graphicspath{{images/}}

    \renewcommand\bibname{Bibliographie}

  \makeindex
```

**image:**

[image]

Comment: Please make your example compilable!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: So I have edited my code. Please take a look. The latex template is from my university I think the commands.tex file includs some deprecated but it works for me.

Comment: Don't use `\include` in the preamble; for the `commands.tex` file use `\input{commands}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the template you're using could be improved, or at least tidied up. However, if it's working for you, and the only problem is to remove the word "Listings" from the header, since you are already using `fancyhdr` you can simply add:

```
\cleardoublepage %To end \lstlistoflistings
\fancyhead{} %Cleans the header
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %Uncomment if you want to remove the header rule, too.
```

after the `\lstlistoflistings` command. If you want to restore the previous style after the figure, you have to copy and paste the code inside `command.tex`:

```
\fancyhf{} % Delete all fields
%\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
```

In this case it could be better to define a list of styles, for example:

```
% Main style definition
\fancypagestyle{myMainStyle}{%
    \fancyhf{} % Delete all fields
    %\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
}

% Other style definition - to remove headers
\fancypagestyle{myOtherStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Cleans the header
    %\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %Uncomment if you want to remove the header rule, too.
}
```

and switch between them inside the main document using:

```
...

\lstlistoflistings

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{myOtherStyle} %Removes the header

% Figures...

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{myMainStyle} %Restores the previous style

...
```

One final remark: if you want to add non-floating images, you don't need the `figure` environment, you only need:

```
{\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}
\captionof{figure}{Figure caption}
\label{...}
}
```

Comment: `captionof` can mess up the caption numbering. See David Carlisle's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254565/44160 for a fix if you want to mix `captionof` with "real" `caption`s.

Comment: @1010011010 This might happen if there are floating figures "near" these non-floating objects, AFAIK. Since the OP seems to add these figure at the very end of the document (before the bibliography), I think that this problem won't happen. Thank you for your suggestion :)!