# Grouped `\fill`s

Tags: spacing, fill, glue

Is it possible to have an environment like `{itemfill}` that would behave something like `\begin{itemize}[itemsep=\fill]` from the [enumerate](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) package, so that, in the imaginary code sample:

```
\documentclass{mwe}
\newenvironment{itemfill}{ %%What goes here?
    }{}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemfill}
\item A1
\item A2
\end{itemfill}

\begin{itemfill}
\item B1
\item B2
\item B3
\end{itemfill}
\end{document}
```

each `{itemfill}` environment would occupy about half the page, with approximately one half of the vertical space on the page between `A1` and `A2`, and approximately one quarter of the vertical space on the page between each consecutive pair of `B1`, `B2`, and `B3`?

(In this particular example, I could do

```
\documentclass{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item A1
\vfill\vfill
\item A2
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item B1
\vfill
\item B2
\vfill
\item B3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

but I want the counting done automatically for me.  By comparison, `\begin{itemize}[itemsep=\fill]` puts approximately equal space between each pair of items, with no concern for their semantic grouping, so that there would be roughly one third of the vertical space between `A1` and `A2`, and roughly one third between each consecutive pair of `B1`, `B2`, and `B3`.)

Comment: You can create proportional glue using something like `\advance \itemsep by 0pt  plus 2fil`

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thanks!  And of course [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631121/grouped-fills#comment1573885_631121)'s better than my repeated `\vfill` solution.  But it still requires me to count manually.  I'd like a way to say "allot this unit as much vertical space as if I'd said `\vfill` when comparing it to other glue on the page, but allocate that vertical space equally among however many items are in the list."

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230464/pgfplots-placing-legends-individually-to-the-end-of-lines/238464?r=SearchResults&s=1|25.0120#238464 interesting.

Comment: I will have a look at [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631121/grouped-fills#comment1573991_631121), although it seems likely to take some time to digest.  Thank you for the link.